# HTML diagonal grid - for a game

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm attempting to create a birds eye view game in HTML and Javascript.
I've found a JSFiddle example of something similar to what I'd like to accomplish using CSS transform: `transform:rotate(-45deg);`
http://jsfiddle.net/Tbucy/
The only problems I see with it are:
1. I'd like the birds eye view to be at an angle, rather than directly straight down.
2. The game view will be based over a village which can expand through all 4 sides (top, left, right, bottom). With a normal table (using x and y coordinates) I expect expanding the table to minus coordinates will be a problem. I think the best solution for this will be to place everything inside an HTML canvas, however I don't know for sure if a canvas will cause perspective issues, or even how to create the canvas to work for the game.

Does anyone have any resources, or can anyone give me any insight on what the best path would be to accomplish what I'd like to do?

Comment: CSS perspective may help you, please have a look at this http://xy-kao.com/projects/virtual-graphics-for-swimming/ this page also contains a demo

Comment: Try searching for "isometric" instead of "diagonal grid".

Comment: here is some nice example: http://codepen.io/johan/pen/yGDoI

Comment: @DavorMlinaric Your codepen has the non-webkit properties missing. It's not that I don't _have_ Chrome, but you might issue a warning before letting people look at your codepen with their default browsers and conclude that it does nothing.

Comment: @MrLister yes, true... my bad. i didn't check code, found this example once before so i share it because it looked like something he need.